# Javascript | How to stop a function that is running on a website

Tags: javascript, php, html

So, I've got a script that allows the user that goes on my website to activate like a rain feature. But I want them to be able to turn it off? The thing is that I don't have a clue on how to do this and I've tried many different things like break, return, some timeout thing, but nothing has given result, so I'm turning to you people who are smart and know this more then I do :)

Here is the script and I activate the script from a button press with onclick event.

```
var amountOfDrops = 150; 
var started = false;
function randRange( minNum, maxNum) {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);}
// function to generate drops
function createRain() {
if (started ===  false){

    for( i=1;i<amountOfDrops;i++) {
    var dropLeft = randRange(0,2400);
    var dropTop = randRange(-1000,1400);

    $('.rain').append('<div class="drop" id="drop'+i+'"></div>');
    $('#drop'+i).css('left',dropLeft);
    $('#drop'+i).css('top',dropTop);
    }
                            console.log("Start");
                            console.log(started);
                            started = !started; //flips the bool to stop
}else{
                                    console.log("Shut down");
                            console.log(started);
                            started = !started; //flips the bool to start
                            return false;
}}
```

I have searched around on the internet but I can't find anything about it so help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT(1)

So, let me fill in some gaps.

This is my CSS for it:

```
.drop {
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0%,0% 100%, from(rgba(13,52,58,1) ), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.6))  );
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(13,52,58,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.6) 100%);
    width:1px;
    height:89px;
                  color: #5cb1d1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:200px;
    -webkit-animation: fall .63s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: fall .63s linear infinite;

}

/* animate the drops*/
@-webkit-keyframes fall {
    to {margin-top:900px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes fall {
    to {margin-top:900px;}
}
```

This is how i call it in the html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Rain.js"></script>
<button onclick="createRain()">Start Rain</button>
```

Comment: how are you calling the createRain function()

Comment: Are you calling the `createRain` function from loop or using setTimeout? If not then you can remove all html element from `.rain` component.

Comment: Remove the two start = !started from the if and else loop. They're the values read by the loop and you want to manipulate them outside if this animation is infinite and toggled by button. It would also be wiser to use "true" and "false" when toggling specifically. You should also check started after you changed started to make sure it is in the preferred state.

Comment: @ishwarrimal I edited the post but it is <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Rain.js"></script>
<button onclick="createRain()">Start Rain</button>

Comment: @lkdhruw I'ts a button on the main home page (See my edit)

Answer (score 1):

I think we can solve this problem using setInterval(). It works for me just check it out.

```js
var amountOfDrops = 150; 
var started = false;
function randRange( minNum, maxNum) {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);}
// function to generate drops
function createRain(started) {
if (started ===  false){

    for( i=1;i<amountOfDrops;i++) {
    var dropLeft = randRange(0,2400);
    var dropTop = randRange(-1000,1400);

    $('.rain').append('<div class="drop" id="drop'+i+'"></div>');
    $('#drop'+i).css('left',dropLeft);
    $('#drop'+i).css('top',dropTop);
    }
                            
}else{
                                   
                            
                            started = !started; //flips the bool to start
                            return false;
}}


$(document).on("click",".start",function(){
 started = false;
 setInterval(function(){
  createRain(started)
 },200)
})
$(document).on("click",".end",function(){
 started = true;
 setInterval(function(){
  createRain(started)
 },200)
 $(".drop").remove()
})
```

```css
body{
   background-color: #000000;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  .btn{
   border: 1px solid #ffffff;
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: transparent;
   margin: 20px auto;
      padding:5px 20px;
  }
  .btn:hover{
   color: #eeeeee;
  }
  .drop{
     background-color: #000;
     width: 1px;
     height: 3px;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     position: relative;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="btn end">End</button>
  <button class="btn start">Start</button>
 </div>
 <div class="rain">
  
 </div>
```

Comment: This code works but it becomes super laggy after sometime? Do you know the reason or if there was a fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a setInterval and then have a setTimeout for a clearInterval. Just a thought and this could be in or outside the function. Also, I'm pretty sure that JavaScript doesn't execute the `console.log()` and flips the boolean until the for statement is done. So the best way to go is a setInterval then have a clearInterval, whether a setTimeout or just a click of the button.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, 
you can try to add a timer to your function
and you can use :

```
$('#someElement').click(function(){
    // Clear the timeout
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```